# Automatically generate OpenApi specification for Google Cloud Endpoints app using Maven

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, openapi

I've created a new Google Cloud Endpoints app using Java and the Maven framework. It has a single servlet and only a basic `doGet` method

```
public void doGet ... etc.
```

I'm supposed to be able to generate an endpoints document using:

```
mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs
```

This is described in the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java#generating_the_openapi_configuration_file)

I just get a message though that contains the text:

```
Generates an OpenAPI document

Usage: <Endpoints tool> get-openapi-doc <options> <service class>...
```

In another existing endpoints project that contains a number of services, running `mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs` works, and I get the message:

```
OpenAPI document written to C:\myFolder\my-project\target\openapi-docs\openapi.json
```

I need to create a basic OpenApi document structure. Does `mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs` only work if I have services defined in my Endpoints? I'm confused as to why the command works, and creates an `openapi.json` in the existing project, but not the other. What do I need to do for `mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs` to create an `openapi.json`? Or can a `get-openapi-doc` instruction be used to do this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the Google documentation for doing this:

[Adding API Management](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management)